# how to close my python loop after user tried three time

Tags: python

I made a loop which gives the user the chance to guess the right number. The problem is that my loop is continuing after the user guesses the right or wrong number. I want that the user can try up to three times. If they can't guess the right number within three chances then the loop will be closed.

Here is my code:

```
secret_number = 9
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3

while guess_count < guess_limit:
    try:
        give_number = int(float(input("give your number: ")))
        if give_number == secret_number:
            print("you won")
        elif give_number != secret_number:
            print("you guess wrong number")
    except ValueError:
        print("only integer or float value allowed")
```

Comment: try adding `guess_count +=1` in your `elif` portion

Comment: After the `input()` function is called, no matter guess is right or wrong, the user has already guessed one time, so it's necessary to +1 to the `guess_count` variable.

Comment: I already get my answare thanks all.  I think stackoverflow is very helpful community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to inclement value by 1 otherwise you loop will be continue.

```
secret_number = 9
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3

while guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess_count += 1
    try:
        give_number = int(float(input("give your number: ")))
        if give_number == secret_number:
            print("you won")
        elif give_number != secret_number:
            print("you guess wrong number")
    except ValueError:
        print("only integer or float value allowed")
else:
    guess_count = guess_limit
    print("you tried maximum time")
```

Comment: thank u farhan you explanation and code was very easy for understand me

Answer (score 0):

```py
secret_number = 9
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3

while guess_count < guess_limit:
    try:
        give_number = int(float(input("give your number: ")))
        if give_number == secret_number:
            print("you won")
            break# break loop
        elif give_number != secret_number:
            print("you guess wrong number")
    except ValueError:
        print("only integer or float value allowed")
    else:
        guess_count += 1# increment count
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should increase the `guess_count`, Doing that will make the loop automatically exit after 3 tries.

Also, you should include a `break` if the user guesses correctly. The break keyword exits the loop immediately.

```
secret_number = 9
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3

while guess_count < guess_limit:
    try:
        give_number = int(float(input("give your number: ")))
        if give_number == secret_number:
            print("you won")
            break
        elif give_number != secret_number:
            print("you guess wrong number")
        guess_count += 1
    except ValueError:
        print("only integer or float value allowed")
```